# C# Serialisation to jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

I am trying to populate some graph data in javascript with some C# code

Here is the C#:

```
 var publicationTable = new[] {
    new[] { month.Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.RoomCount)).ToArray() },
    new[] { month.Select(x => x.HoursCount).ToArray()  }
};

return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(publicationTable);
```

Javascript:

```
height: 375,
xGrid: false,
legend: true,
title: 'Meetings and Hours Used (Coming Soon!)',
points: <%= getJson() %>,
```

The following C# code works:

```
public string getJson() {

var publicationTable = new[] {
    new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
    new[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
};
return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(publicationTable);
}
```

Month is a List with elements RoomCount(int) and HoursCount(Float)

[image: Output]

Edited to say: It looks like the whole serialisation is being put in the first element of the graph (see image)

Comment: Please post the actual rendered response.

Comment: points: [[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6]],[[0,0,0,0,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,9,10,10,10,11,11,12,13,14,14,15,16,17,17,18,19,20,20,21,22,23,23,24]]],

Comment: It seems to have an extra set of [] round it - how do I go about removing them?

Comment: The code looks correct, but the `month` variable seems to have more than one month's data inside of it. Could you post it please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var publicationTable = new[] {
    month.Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.RoomCount)).ToArray(),
    month.Select(x => x.HoursCount).ToArray()
};
```

The `.toArray()` is already returning an array, so it's not needed the `new[]` (that way you are creating an array, with the first element being another array)